# SQl query on max summation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I've got two tables

**Unit**

```
Unit_id
Unit_name
Unit_cost
```

**Components**

```
Component_id
Component_name
Unit_id
```

They are linked together by `Unit_id`.

I need the single **Unit_name** of the one unit that has the highest total cost (Unit.Unit_cost), with all of the Components linked to the Units table by the **Unit_id**.  Note I just need the **Unit_Name** only, not total cost.

Would it be best to use a "Top(1)" in the query?  How would the query look?

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results. The `unit_cost` is in the `unit` table, so it is unclear what the use of `components` is for your query.

Comment: you can use `rank()` function

Comment: I will re post my question on a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want all components linked to the top-cost unit.

If so, you have a couple of options. You can use window functions to rank records per unit cost:

```
select *
from (
    select u.unit_name, c.*, rank() over(order by u.unit_cost desc) rn
    from unit u
    inner join components c on c.unit_id = u.unit_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Or you can join with a query that gets the top unit; assuming that your database supports T-SQL syntax `top (1)` (which you mentionned in your question):

```
select u.unit_name, c.*
from (select top(1) with ties * from unit order by unit_cost desc) u
inner join components c on c.unit_id = u.unit_id
```

Both queries allow ties: if different units have the maximum cost, both their components will be listed.